# in sqlite how to check the table is empty or not?

Tags: sqlite

I need the check the table is empty or not 
 **employee table contains columns are id name**

```
id  name
1   john 
2   hunter
3   smith
4   will
```

Answer (score 2):

If your table can contain a lot of rows, you can win some time with

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (select 0 from employee limit 1);
```

Comment: it's your query very nice but the optimized query is (select 1 from employee limit 1;) , is that efficient and simple query

Comment: Yes, but handling the result is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

A table is empty if `select count(*) from employee` returns 0.

Comment: it takes to much time and in worst case it have ten thousand rows it count all the rows, so it take too much amount of time